# How to make &mut self from &self?

Tags: rust

I want to expose a public function with immutable self which calls a private function with mutable self.

```
struct Foo {
    value: i32,
}

impl Foo {
    fn f1(&self) {
        self.f2(); // <--- is it possible to make self mutable?
    }

    fn f2(&mut self) {
        self.value = 5;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo { value: 0 };
    foo.f1();
}
```

When compiling this code I get an error

> cannot borrow immutable borrowed content `*self` as mutable

Is it possible to make self mutable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT:

After missing that last sentence.. you *could* get away with wrapping the property in a `Cell`:

```
use std::cell::Cell;

struct Foo { value: Cell<i32> }

impl Foo {
  fn f1(&self) {
    self.f2();
  }

  fn f2(&self) {
    self.value.set(5);
  }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo { value: Cell::new(0) };
    foo.f1();
    println!("{:?}", foo.value.get()); // prints 5
}
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting let mut foo, but my goal is for f1 function definition to remain fn f1(&self)

Comment: I only just noticed that sentence. Unfortunately as far as I am aware that isn't possible on a `self` reference. You may be able to get away with using a `RefCell` or similar construct for a property on your object.. but not the object itself.

Answer (score 5):

What you want cannot be done: you cannot convert a non-mutable reference into a mutable one.

But you can get almost that with [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/cell/struct.RefCell.html):

```
struct Foo { value: RefCell<i32> }

impl Foo {
    fn f1(&self) {
        let mutValue = self.value.borrow_mut();
        *mutValue = 5;
    }
}
```

I didn't even need the `f2` function!

Comment: Using `UnsafeCell` is a bad idea; almost always you'd want to use `RefCell` or `Cell`, the latter for `Copy` data.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev: Oh, ok. I've updated the answer with `RefCell` (It could also be done with `Cell`).

Comment: @rodrigo: To expand on Vladimir's point. `UnsafeCell` is the basic unsafe functionality which underlies both `Cell` and `RefCell`, so it is used in the end, what matters is that being `unsafe` you have to be aware of the invariants that your code need to maintain. The authors of `Cell` and `RefCell` are aware of those invariants and have provided a safe interface which maintain them automatically for you; thus making your job easier.