# Cast &self to mut (to use predefined trait where it isn't mut)

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement Allocator:

```
pub unsafe trait Allocator {
    fn allocate(&self, layout: Layout) -> Result<NonNull<[u8]>, AllocError>;
    ...
```

Note that the &self is not mutable. I'm not sure what kind of allocator would be able to allocate without making changes to the allocator itself, but this is what `vec` is prepared to talk to so I guess I have to put up with it. My questions are:

- should they have made the &self mut or am I missing something?
- how do I brutally cast this &self to being mut?

I tried just sticking mut in the impl:

```
unsafe impl Allocator for Mappoc {                         
    fn allocate(&mut self, layout: Layout) -> Result<NonNull<[u8]>, AllocError> { 
    ...
```

but it said:

```
|| error[E0053]: method `allocate` has an incompatible type for trait
src/lib.rs|110| 17
||     |
|| 110 |     fn allocate(&mut self, layout: Layout)
||     |                 ^^^^^^^^^
||     |                 |
||     |                 types differ in mutability
||     |                 help: change the self-receiver type to match the trait: `self: &Mappoc`
||     |
||     = note: expected fn pointer `fn(&Mappoc, std::alloc::Layout) -> Result<_, _>`
||                found fn pointer `fn(&mut Mappoc, std::alloc::Layout) -> Result<_, _>`
```

Comment: use interior mut like mutex

Comment: I believe casting a `&T` to `&mut T` is *always* undefined behavior too, or at the very least if there exist other `&T` references (or you create new ones after creating the `&mut T`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make &mut self from &self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36876962/how-to-make-mut-self-from-self)

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues Indeed: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/transmutes.html "Transmuting an `&` to `&mut` is UB. Transmuting an `&` to `&mut` is *always* UB. No you can't do it. No you're not special."

Comment: Thanks to everybody who helped explain this to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, casting `&self` to `&mut` is undefined behavior and is not allowed even in unsafe code (though the compiler is powerless to prevent you from doing it in an unsafe block). Fortunately, it's not needed.

`allocate()` takes `&self` to allow the allocator to be used from multiple threads. (Remember that a `&mut` reference is exclusive, only one may exist at a time.) The simplest thread-safe way to get a mutable reference out of an immutable one is by wrapping the actual allocator in a mutex:

```
struct MappocAllocator {
    inner: Mutex<Mappoc>,  // your actual allocator
}

impl Allocator for MappocAllocator {
    fn allocate(&self, layout: Layout) -> Result<NonNull<[u8]>, AllocError> { 
        let alloc = self.inner.lock().unwrap();
        // now you have access to `&mut Mappoc` for the duration of the lock
        ...
    }
}
```

> I'm not sure what kind of allocator would be able to allocate without making changes to the allocator itself

This is a misunderstanding of what `&T` means. A shared reference doesn't necessarily imply that the data under it won't change, it means that it's safe to use by multiple actors at once. For example, lock-free mutating APIs always [take `&self`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicU64.html#method.fetch_add).

If the `Mappoc` allocator is written in Rust and is thread-safe (or partly/fully lock-free) itself, then its methods should take `&self` to begin with, and you won't need a mutex (because a mutex or its equivalent will be part of `Mappoc` implementation). If `Mappoc`'s methods take `&mut self`, it means they're **not** safe to be invoked from multiple threads, and it's a good thing that Rust forces you to access them through a mutex. This is the system working exactly as designed.

Finally, some allocators, like `mimalloc` or `jemalloc`, are implemented in C or C++ that does its own locking. But then their Rust fronts don't need `&mut self` either because they invoke the actual allocator through a raw pointer.